# How to connect Pi to 3G

Tags: internet

I'd like to connect my Pi to the Internet via 3G dongle but I am very new to Linux and would welcome some help.
What I've already download and install ppp: `sudo apt-get install ppp` and install Sakis3g.
Ant that's the point where I stopped since when I chosse any give option from Sakis3g (e.g. Connect ...), I'll get an error (e.g. "Failed to connect modem" or something like that).
Below is my Terminal output of `lsusb` command.

[image]

Comment: Does the 3g dongle have a SIM card that works when tested on antoher machine for which the manufacturer provides drivers?

Comment: Have not already tested that. I'll tell you within some of tens minutes when I come to my computer.

Comment: Does that matter the 3G USB device is from different provider (O2) than my SIM service (T-Mobile)?

Comment: It might well matter - phones bought from network providers are usually locked to the network. Dongles might be, or might have hard-coded or hard-to-configure network settings.  I've succesfully used an O2 3g dongle (on O2) under Linux, but not for years and I didn't keep notes.  I do remember that the confidence of knowing it worked on a windows machine that O2 support was useful.

Comment: After playing a while with microSIM in standard SIM slot of the dongle I've got it work on Windows. Noted, the 3G dongle has been recognized as CD device at first.

Comment: It fakes being a CD drive to expose a small flash drive containing the drivers if it's anything like the one I had.

Comment: Yes, AutoRun has been lunch automatically from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue and managed to follow this guide:

https://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-setup-usb-3g-modem-raspberry-pi-using-usbmodeswitch-and-wvdial

Though I didnt use all the steps, I am now able to use my Dongle from 3 Mobile.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm going through the tutorial and sincerely let you guys know how the things are going.

Comment: I've tried to install ppp, usb-modeswitch and wvdial but got following error: [link]http://s12.postimg.org/h44g6vykd/install_All_That_Stafs.png[/link] - "Permission denied" and "are you root?" It's odd since I should be.

Comment: Perhaps start a new session and do 'su' and try again if you havent done so

Comment: yep, it already runs.

Comment: btw, could I run Raspbian on VirtualBox and test 3G capability there for better convenience?

Comment: I followed the steps but when I lsusb and root, I always see the dongle is in the same mode (is not switching automatically after reboot). [link]http://s29.postimg.org/pgp9pb8av/Modem_Mode_Target_Product.png[/link]. How can it be switched between storage and modem mode?

Comment: In keeping with our policy regarding informationless link-only answers, if this post is not edited to contain information that can stand as an answer, however minimal, in 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki to simplify having it corrected by the community.